# When a law specifies that documents should be available for examination at "convenient times", for which party should it be convenient?

Tags: legal-terms

**Michigan Compiled Law, CONDOMINIUM ACT (EXCERPT) Act 59 of 1978**

[Section 559.157](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(5wcmadk5saalabl4dbez2p4x))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectName=mcl-559-157) covers books, records, contracts, and financial statements; examination; audit or review; opt-out of requirements of subsection. This law requires a condo without our income level to be audited by a third party, which our property manager has not done. Additionally, we have not voted to waive this requirement.

The law gives me the power to sue, but I would bear 1/7th the costs paid to me because of my portion of ownership. Additionally, I do not want to hurt my relationship with 6 neighbors (one of which is the property manager). Instead, I wish to use the right to inspect defined here:

> The books, records, contracts, and financial statements concerning the
>   administration and operation of the condominium project shall be
>   available for examination by any of the co-owners and their mortgagees
>   at convenient times.

The property manager (who owns a unit) has a place of business where the records are held, and they are open Saturdays. However, I cannot determine if the word "convenience" means that I should be able to review documents on a Saturday or if the convenience is the property manager's own convenience. Could he say that I can only review on a Tuesday at 10:30 AM, for instance?

**Overall, my question is about the legal intention of "convenience":**

- Whose convenience? Can I insist on Saturday so that I don't miss work?
- Does this convenience require a written note with tracked signature or can I drop in during operating hours? Something in between?

Comment: "Convenient times" when you are requesting documents from a business, would mean that businesses normal hours. It would be unreasonable to ask a business to open and make themselves available during off hours. Is the business where the records are kept legally responsible for those documents, or are they just stored there?

Comment: There are only 7 units, and one owner is also acting as the manager for common area bills and building maintenance etc. His main business is an unrelated industry, but an accountant works for him and does the book keeping of the fees and expenses. The business is open Saturdays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "convenient time" is a time that is convenient to both parties acting reasonably. See [What does "reasonable" mean?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/what-does-reasonable-mean/31983#31983)